# Play build.scala to build.sbt isn't working for secureSocial plugin. I don't understand why?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2, securesocial

I'm new in playFrameWork
I'm trying to figure out how the build.sbt file works in play framework 2.2
i'm also trying to make the secureSocial plugin works

In the sample app of the plugin secureSocial, there is a built.scala containing :

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName         = "SecureTestApp"
    val appVersion      = "1.0"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
      "ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "master-SNAPSHOT"
    )
    val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
      resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")
    )
}
```

Whith the command play run, everything wrok fine and the page is showing itself
AnyWay, as i understand it, i should be able to delete project/built.scala and replace it by /build.sbt. i think my file is ok and look like this :

```
name := "SecureTestApp"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "master-SNAPSHOT"
)

resolvers += Resolver.url("Scala Sbt", url("http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-snapshots"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")

play.Project.playScalaSettings
```

This time the play run command work fine the server launch itself but when i launch  and test the app homePage, 
i get the error : Compilation error "object RuntimeEnvironment is not a member of package securesocial.core"

Play is no longer able to find the package secureSocial. And i don't understand why?
What am i doing wrong?

is there a parametter someWhere to set?

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Edit : whith the line

```
"ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1.3"
```

put in both file, play doensn't fine the dependency in both for package secureSocial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that this object simply does not exist in the version that is published to the repository. If you take a look at the [sources](http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-snapshots/securesocial/securesocial_2.10/master-SNAPSHOT/jars/securesocial_2.10.jar), there is no file `RuntimeEnvironment.scala` in which it is supposed to be defined.

Further if you check the date when the file appeared on github it is 7th May, and the last modified date in the [repo](http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-snapshots/securesocial/securesocial_2.10/master-SNAPSHOT/jars/) shows `23-Jan-2014`.

So the bottom line is that your build is working just fine, but the library you're using is not the one that in in the `master` branch on the github at the moment.

Comment: Ok, i think i did a rookie mistake on github thinking that the master was actually the last release version. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should rather use the last stable version :

```
      "ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1.3"
```

and as resolver

```
       resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")
```

as master constantly evolves and the doc might not been updated yet.

Major changes have been made on master the 7th May which might break your project if your created it before. (You could also try to clean-all maybe)

Comment: Thank you, i tried this whith both file. Whith build.sbt, my play app is still not finding the securesocial.core package. But now even whith the build.scala, play doesn't fine the dependancy